# Extjs with Rails- Problem in adding button dynamically on Panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, extjs, panel

I am using ExtJS 3.2.1 with Rails 3.x.
I have a Panel on which I want to add ExtJS Buttons "dynamically" depending upon the number of records in the db. I tried googling but no luck.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not clear in your question where you are adding the button. Are you adding it into a toolbar or into buttons section of a panel. Either way, you should be able to use the `addButton` method available for `Toolbar` and `Panel`.

```
panel.addButton({your button config});
```

Now, to create buttons you will have to wrap it in a loop. Before that you will have to get the necessary data from DB. For getting data, you can use the `Ext.Ajax` class and according to the response, iterate and create the buttons.